# Android : Async Callback

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-asynctask

How to implement a method to return callback object, so i can get the result in callback like this

```
resultObj.onSuccess()
.onFailure()
```

I know i can implement this behavior by defining event methods in interface like the code below

```
val obj = CustomObj()

obj.addOnSuccessListener(object: CustomObjListener {
@Override
fun onSuccess(){
}
})
```

Please advise is it possible to achieve or share your ideas

I want to achieve the process that networking api in react-native does,

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network

```
fun getResult(){
    val promise =  fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
return promise

}

val promise = getResult

  promise.then((response) => response.json())  
        .then((responseJson) => {
          return responseJson.movies;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
```

Similar to the **promise** concept in Javascript.

Comment: Please elaborate on your question and explain your overall goal, and add some sample code or docs that you checked

Comment: If I am getting it correctly, you want to set `onSuccess` and `onFailure` callbacks backto back... tell me if I am wrong...

Comment: @HarshvardhanJoshi Correct!, but need to handle that from a methods return value, one class have multiple methods that all need to achieve this same behavior

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set callbacks back to back like the javascript example you updated, you need to use `Future` API to achieve the same callback chain as the javascript example.

[`Future`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) kotlin/java/dart is equivalent to the `Promise` in JS.

**But** In kotlin `Future`, `Promise` and `coroutine` all are available.
**`coroutines`** are recommended to achieve the same results.

You can refer to these articles for more details:

- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/coroutines/async-programming.html
- https://medium.com/@elizarov/futures-cancellation-and-coroutines-b5ce9c3ede3a

However, If you want to chain function calls for multiple methods in your class, you can use [`Builder Pattern`](https://www.baeldung.com/creational-design-patterns#1-builder-pattern-example) approach in defining your functions.

In this pattern, all the setter methods return the instance of the class.
For example:

```
class BankAccountBuilder(name:String, accountNumber:String) {
  private val name:String
  private val accountNumber:String
  private val email:String
  private val newsletter:Boolean = false
  init{
    this.name = name
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber
  }
  fun withEmail(email:String):BankAccountBuilder {
    this.email = email
    return this
  }
  fun wantNewsletter(newsletter:Boolean):BankAccountBuilder {
    this.newsletter = newsletter
    return this
  }
  fun build():BankAccount {
    return BankAccount(this)
  }
}
```

Now you can just call multiple setters like following:

```
BankAccount.BankAccountBuilder("Jon", "22738022275")
.withEmail("jon@example.com")
.wantNewsletter(true)
.build()
```

similarly whatever functions you want to call on an instance,  just make them return the `instance` itself. you don't have to implement this whole pattern.

Comment: Note that we don't usually use the Builder pattern in Kotlin due to the presence of default/optional parameters and data classes. Using a `data class` and then using .copy(a = 1) when you want to modify it is generally better than using a Builder, and due to the allowance of defaults a builder is not needed to construct the initial instance. Also, your formatting is a bit off (lots of missing spaces) :P

Comment: I agree. It's Only that, it doesn't allow chaining calls on an object like it does in builder pattern. Thanks for the formatting tip.

Comment: it does allow chaining it. try this: `data class A(val a: String, val b: String = "i'm a b"); fun test() = A("hi").copy(b="i'm no longer b").copy(a="bye")`. That has chaining and (should) compile

Comment: Thanks @HarshvardhanJoshi, Will check the Future Api, it look interesting

Answer (score 0):

By the way i have some simple solutions,

1. Passing the callback method,

```
          private fun getResults(request:String ,callback: (String)->Unit){
             callback("200")
          }

          getResults("request",fun(response:String){
            //code
          })
```

2. Create Listener & pass the listener object

```
  val listener = object : ResultListener {
     override fun onSuccess(response: Any?, statusCode: Int?) {
         Log.d("apps", "onSuccess: $response")
     }

     override fun onFailed(response: Any?, statusCode: Int?) {
         Log.d("apps", "onFailed: $response")
     }

 }

 getResults(listener)


 private fun getResults(resultListener: ResultListener) {
         resultListener.onSuccess("Success Listener Invoked", 200)
         resultListener.onFailed("Failed Listener Invoked", 200)

 }
```

I like the **second solution** using listener.